# Office 365 unified API (preview)

Tags: azure, office365, azure-active-directory

How do you get access to the old apis?

In my azure account I have Office 365 unified API (preview), I wish to use the old APIs because it's in preview, poorly documented and sluggish.

However in my azure account I only have Office 365 unified API (preview), Office 365 Management APIs & Windows Azure Active Directory permissions to choose from.

Answer (score 0):

In order for the Office 365 APIs to appear in "Permissions to other applications" on the Azure AD app configuration / registration portal, the Azure AD directory needs an Office 365 account (tenant) associated with it.

Here's an easy way to get going.

Sign up for the Office 365 Developer Program at http://dev.office.com/devprogram. It is currently offering a free Office 365 Developer tenant.

Associate your existing Azure subscription with the new Office 365 Developer tenant.

- Log on to Microsoft Azure Management portal with your Azure credentials, e.g. user@live.com
- Select Active Directory node, then select Directory tab and select New (bottom of screen).
- On the New menu, select Active Directory > Directory > Custom Create.
- In Add directory wizard, select "Use existing directory". Check "I am ready to be signed out" and when prompted log in with your new Office 365 Developer account information.
- Select continue, and then Sign out now.
- Log on again to the Azure Management Portal with your Azure credentials, e.g. user@live.com, and navigate to the Active Directory node.

You should now see the directory of Office 365 Developer tenant. At this point you'll have the Office 365 APIs when you configure / register a new application in this Azure AD directory.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/office/office365/HowTo/setup-development-environment